# JAXB - empty tags with no xsi:nil

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, jaxb2, xsi

I have a String property in an object annotated as follows:

```
@XmlElement(name = "Item", required = true, nillable = true)
private String item;
```

The result after marshaling is

```
<Item xsi:nil="true"/>
```

while I would like it to be

```
<Item/>
```

since the third-party service accepting my XML messages wants it like the latter case. I am using jaxb2. Does anyone knows how I could possibly do this?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note:**  I'm the [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) lead and a member of the [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) expert group.

The following example requires the use of MOXy as the JAXB provider.  This is because the JAXB RI does not call the `XmlAdapter` when the field/property is null.  For information on specifying MOXy as your JAXB provider see:

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/05/specifying-eclipselink-moxy-as-your.html

**StringAdapter**

The `XmlAdapter` will convert the String value to an object with a property annotated with `@XmlValue`.

```
package forum8986842;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter;

public class StringAdapter extends XmlAdapter<StringAdapter.AdaptedString, String>{

    @Override
    public String unmarshal(AdaptedString adaptedString) throws Exception {
        if(null == adaptedString) {
            return null;
        }
        String string = adaptedString.value;
        if("".equals(string)) {
            return null;
        }
        return string;
    }

    @Override
    public AdaptedString marshal(String string) throws Exception {
        AdaptedString adaptedString = new AdaptedString();
        adaptedString.value = string;
        return adaptedString;
    }

    public static class AdaptedString {
        @XmlValue public String value;
    }

}
```

**Root**

The `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter` annotation is used to specify the `XmlAdapter`:

```
package forum8986842;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlJavaTypeAdapter;

@XmlRootElement(name="Root")
public class Root {

    private String item;

    @XmlElement(name = "Item", required = true, nillable = true)
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(StringAdapter.class)
    public String getItem() {
        return item;
    }

    public void setItem(String item) {
        this.item = item;
    }

}
```

**Demo**

The following code can be used to demonstrate the above mapping.  Two documents are used one with an empty `Item` element, and the other with a populated `Item` element.

```
package forum8986842;

import java.io.StringReader;
import javax.xml.bind.*;

public class Demo {

    private JAXBContext jc;

    public Demo() throws JAXBException {
        jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Root.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Demo demo = new Demo();
        demo.demo("<Root><Item/></Root>");
        demo.demo("<Root><Item>Hello World</Item></Root>");
    }

    private void demo(String xml) throws JAXBException {
        System.out.println("\n\nINPUT:  " + xml);
        StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(xml);
        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        Root root = (Root) unmarshaller.unmarshal(stringReader);

        System.out.println("ITEM:   " + root.getItem());

        System.out.print("OUTPUT: ");
        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FRAGMENT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(root, System.out);
    }

}
```

**Output**

The following is the output from running the demo code:

```
INPUT:  <Root><Item/></Root>
ITEM:   null
OUTPUT: <Root><Item/></Root>

INPUT:  <Root><Item>Hello World</Item></Root>
ITEM:   Hello World
OUTPUT: <Root><Item>Hello World</Item></Root>
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/05/specifying-eclipselink-moxy-as-your.html
- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/06/jaxb-and-complex-types-with-simple.html
- http://blog.bdoughan.com/search/label/XmlAdapter

Answer (score -1):

I found changing the xsd was easier

```
<xs:element name="name">
   <xs:complexType/>
</xs:element>
```

and in your code, when you auto generate your java src/classes

you would specify new Name and set the Name to whichever object name belongs under